# S3 static hosting - path without index.html

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We have multiple Angular projects which we like to quickly upload to s3 for QA & testing.
We upload all of them to the same bucket, in different subfolders. So the s3 bucket structure is as following:

```
 -- tests-bucket
    -- project1
       -- index.html
    -- project2
       -- index.html
```

We then have a cloud front distribution and route53 setup e.g. tests.domain.com.

When accessing the projects via the full path everything works:

```
tests.domain.com/project1/index.html
tests.domain.com/project2/index.html
```

However, when we try accessing the project without index.html (`tests.domain.com/project1` or `tests.domain.com/project1/`) we get the following error:

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>index.html</Key>
<RequestId></RequestId>
<HostId></HostId>
</Error>
```

This makes it hard for us to test, since after the initial page load, the `index.html` is automatically removed and any additional reload will lead to a 404 error.

The bucket is set to serve website static hosting and both index and error documents point to `index.html`.

The CloudFront distribution is also set to have a 404 error path redirect to index.html.

It seems as this setup only works for the root path of the bucket `tests.domain.com/index.html` but does not support subdirectories.

[This AWS article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html) makes it seems possible, but in our case, it does not work with an SPA/Angular application.

From a quick research into this, I found [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-default-directory-indexes-in-amazon-s3-backed-amazon-cloudfront-origins-using-lambdaedge/) which resolves this issue using a Lamda Edge redirect, but the setup seems a bit overkill, plus only seems to support the US East distribution.

Is there any simple configuration that can resolve this, using only s3/cloudfront/route53 which does not involve lambda functions?

Comment: You aren't using the S3 website hosting endpoint, which is where index documents are implemented.  See the duplicate question.  The XML errors are *only* returned by the REST endpoint, which does not support index documents.

Comment: The Lambda@Edge solution you found, [Implementing Default Directory Indexes in Amazon S3-backed Amazon CloudFront Origins Using Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-default-directory-indexes-in-amazon-s3-backed-amazon-cloudfront-origins-using-lambdaedge/) is only needed if you need to mix index documents with private content, in which case, there is not another solution.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thank you! My DNS indeed was indeed configured to the CloudFront and not the s3 endpoint. I updated it and waiting for the changes to take place in order to test. Much appreciated!

Comment: Also see [AWS docs for Website Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteEndpoints.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

2022 EDIT:

You can now accomplish this logic by setting the CloudFront Default Root Object (as defined [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html)) instead of applying the below answer. The below answer continues to work if for whatever reason the easier option does not.

---

Original Answer:

Yes, you can configure this using the "index-document" property when you're enabling website hosting in your bucket. Check out the CLI documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/website.html

When you enable this functionality, it will be enabled on every path that doesn't end in a file. So requesting "/project1/" would return "/project1/index.html" if you set your index-document property to "index.html"

More documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HostingWebsiteOnS3Setup.html

When using Cloudfront, the default root object behavior in cloudfront will override the index-document usage from S3. To get around this behavior, don't use a S3 origin, and instead use a custom origin and pass through your S3 bucket URL as the origin domain name.

Documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html (specifically, "However, if you define a default root object, an end-user request for a subdirectory of your distribution does not return the default root object. For example, suppose index.html is your default root object and that CloudFront receives an end-user request for the install directory under your CloudFront distribution")

Comment: Thanks but that still doesn't work. I already set it as `index.html` and mentioned it in my question. It doesn't seem to support subdirectories. Are you sure this should work? For me `root/` will serve `root/index.html` but `root/project1/` will not serve `root/project1/index.html`.

Comment: Yeah, and I just tested it in one of my buckets as well before I responded. Their documentation is pretty explicit that the configuration works in every sub-folder:

"If you create such a folder structure in your bucket, you must have an index document at each level. When a user specifies a URL that resembles a folder lookup, the presence or absence of a trailing slash determines the behavior of the website. For example, the following URL, with a trailing slash, returns the photos/index.html index document. http://example-bucket.s3-website-region.amazonaws.com/photos/ "

Comment: Hmmm very weird. Still not working over here. I have index.html under each folder and the index document is set. Perhaps has to do with SSL?

Comment: I somehow completely missed that you have it set to use Cloudfront, and caught that when you mentioned SSL. Since you have this set up in Cloudfront, Cloudfront's default root object detection is overriding your s3 index-document (assuming you have it set up as a s3 origin). If you change Cloudfront to use a custom origin and point it to the s3 hosted URL, it should resolve your issue. I'll edit the answer to include that detail as well.

Comment: Testing it now, makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Unable to edit the answer because "Suggested edit queue is full". Long answer short, Go to CloudFront -> General -> Edit -> "Default root object - optional" and in the textbox input `index.html`.

Comment: @mdabdullah - I haven't tested recently, are you suggesting that setting the cloudfront default root object now allows this without using a custom endpoint? I can test that out and edit the answer if so (since I think a lot of people still view this answer).

Comment: Yes @Patrick that is correct, please do so if you can! I wanted to add a screenshot but funny that even now, 24 hours later I am getting the same error when I try to edit the message.

Comment: @mdabdullah - Done.