# Cloudfront distribution fails to load subdirectories in one stack but works in another

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, serverless-framework

I'm using cloudformation (via serverless framework) to deploy static sites to S3 and set up a cloudfront distribution that is aliased from a route53 domain.

I have this working for two domains, each are new domains that were created in route53. I am trying the same set up with an older domain that I am transferring to route53 from an existing registrar.

The cloudfront distribution for this new domain fails to load sub directories. I.e `https://[mydistid].cloudfront.net/sub/dir/` does not load the resource at `https://[mydistid].cloudfront.net/sub/dir/index.html`

There is a common gotcha covered in [other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50770157/s3-static-hosting-path-without-index-html). You must specify the s3 bucket as a custom origin, in order for CloudFront to apply the Default Root Object to sub directories.

I have done this, as can be seen from my serverless.yml CloudFrontDistribution resource:

```
    XxxxCloudFrontDistribution:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
      Properties:
        DistributionConfig:
          Aliases:
            - ${self:provider.environment.CUSTOM_DOMAIN}
          Origins:
            - DomainName: ${self:provider.environment.BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com
              Id: Xxxx
              CustomOriginConfig:
                HTTPPort: 80
                HTTPSPort: 443
                OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
          Enabled: 'true'
          DefaultRootObject: index.html
          CustomErrorResponses:
            - ErrorCode: 404
              ResponseCode: 200
              ResponsePagePath: /error.html
          DefaultCacheBehavior:
            AllowedMethods:
              - DELETE
              - GET
              - HEAD
              - OPTIONS
              - PATCH
              - POST
              - PUT
            TargetOriginId: Xxxx
            Compress: 'true'
            ForwardedValues:
              QueryString: 'false'
              Cookies:
                Forward: none
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
          ViewerCertificate:
            AcmCertificateArn: ${self:provider.environment.ACM_CERT_ARN}
            SslSupportMethod: sni-only
```

This results in the a CF distribution with the s3 bucket as a 'Custom Origin' in AWS.

However, when accessed the sub directories route to the error page rather than the default root object in that directory.

What is extremely odd is that this uses the same config as another stack that is fine. The only diff I can see (so far) is that the working stack has a route53 created domain whereas this uses a domain that originated from another registrar, so I'll see what happens once the name server migration completes. I'm skeptical this will resolve the issue though as the CF distribution shouldn't be affected by the route53 domain status

Comment: Can you confirm if both the stack has same S3 origin ? The working one may have the S3 website endpoint instead of rest api endpoint, e.g: s3-website

Comment: Hi James, I think I know what you mean but in each of the CF distributions, working and not working, the 'Origin Domain Name and Path' fields are both: [bucketName].s3.amazonaws.com

. The domain name server migration is now complete so AFAICT there is no difference between the two stacks now.

Comment: Ah I see - the other SO question shows that the distributions should be pointing to [bucketName].s3-website.us-east-1.amazonaws.com. So I will change both the working and non working stacks over to using that in the next couple of days.  The key learning here is that my working stack actually should not be working...

Answer (score 0):

I have both stacks working now. The problem was the use of the S3 REST API url

`${self:provider.environment.BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com`

Changing both to the s3 website url works:

`${self:provider.environment.BUCKET_NAME}.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

I have no explanation as to why the former URL worked with 1 stack but not the other.

The other change that I needed to make was to set the `OriginProtocolPolicy` of `CustomOriginConfig` to `http-only`, this is because s3 websites don't support https.

Here is my updated CloudFormation config:

```
XxxxCloudFrontDistribution:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
      Properties:
        DistributionConfig:
          Aliases:
            - ${self:provider.environment.CUSTOM_DOMAIN}
          Origins:
            - DomainName: ${self:provider.environment.BUCKET_NAME}.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
              Id: Xxxx
              CustomOriginConfig:
                HTTPPort: 80
                OriginProtocolPolicy: http-only
          Enabled: 'true'
          DefaultRootObject: index.html
          CustomErrorResponses:
            - ErrorCode: 404
              ResponseCode: 200
              ResponsePagePath: /error.html
          DefaultCacheBehavior:
            AllowedMethods:
              - DELETE
              - GET
              - HEAD
              - OPTIONS
              - PATCH
              - POST
              - PUT
            TargetOriginId: Xxxx
            Compress: 'true'
            ForwardedValues:
              QueryString: 'false'
              Cookies:
                Forward: none
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
          ViewerCertificate:
            AcmCertificateArn: ${self:provider.environment.ACM_CERT_ARN}
            SslSupportMethod: sni-only
```